# Downloading a file, can you cancel the response when an error occurs, without buffering the content

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file, httpresponse

I am writing large CSV files to the Response with `Response.BufferOutput` set to false. This is because the file has the potential to take a long time to download so the user can see some progress. I generate a line for the CSV from a object and write to the response using `Response.Write()`.

This works well however if there is an unexpected error after the Response has started writing then the client will receive a file with only part of the data and could be missing lots of lines but they might not realise it.

Is there a way to somehow cancel the file download without buffering all the content? Could there be some way to indicate that the response is invalid so the browser disregards the file?

Code below shows the main idea of my code

```
public void StreamCsvFile(string fileName,List<myObject> myObjectList)
{
   Response.Clear();

   Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
   Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "filename=" + fileName);
   Response.BufferOutput = false;

   string headerLine = GetHeaderLine();
   Response.Write(headerLine)

   try
   {
      foreach(var myObject in myObjectList)
      {
        string line = myObject.ToCsvString();

        Response.Write("\n" + line);
      }
   }
   finally
   {
     Response.End();
   }    
}
```

Comment: Have you tried throwing an exception (and not catching it)?

Answer (score 0):

- Write to a temporary file first.
- Set the content-length on the response.
- Use Response.TransmitFile to send this temp file.
- Browsers will reject download if content length doesn't match.

Comment: Writing to a temporary file doesn't address the concern of allow the user to see some immediate feedback. It is similar to, or worse than, buffering the output.